# How to get UITableView occupied full screen in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I have added 2 view controllers, in one tab view controller.

```
@implementation AppDelegate
.....
.....
self.myTabBarController.viewControllers = @[fvc, mvc];

// Root View Controller. 

self.window.rootViewController = self.myTabBarController;
```

1) The first view controller [ fvc ] has UITableView.

2)  In the portrait mode it is displayed properly,

**Problem:**

Where as, in the landscape mode   UITableView row occupies only half of the screen, 
it is not scaled till end.

I could sense it is something to do with autoresizing.   But '**Attribute Inspector**' shows me that '**Autoresize Subviews**' is enabled.

Kindly provide suggestion.

Comment: Most probably you have autoresizing masks or auto layout constraints set up incorrectly. Please show the Size Inspector screenshot when your table view is selected.

Comment: kambala, i checked on the UITableView atrribute inspector, autosize subviews, and use auto layout both are enabled.

Comment: Could it be the UITableView is expanding but the cell itself isn't set to autoexpand?

Comment: @Whoami The Size Inspector (thing where frame values are displayed)